# Rotating and moving SCNNode in world space

Tags: scenekit

I’m trying to rotate and move a SCNNode. It is acting as if I’m still rotating in local space rather than world space. If I rotate the item and then apply force, it moves in the same direction as before, just pointing in a new direction, rather than ‘forward’ being redefined by the rotation. What am I doing wrong? Thanks.

```
func applyForce(to node: SCNNode) {
    let newTransform = SCNMatrix4Translate(node.worldTransform, force.x, force.y, force.z)
    node.setWorldTransform(newTransform)
}
    
func applyRotation(to node: SCNNode, radians: Float) {
    let newTransform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(node.worldTransform, radians, 0, 1, 0)
    node.setWorldTransform(newTransform)
}
```

Comment: Do you have some more detailed information about your issue? I hardly understand you problem. How is your scene setup? Do you use dynamic physicsBodies? (if yes, there are some default commands to apply force and rotation, which is called torque). It seems, you want to implement your own force and rotation functions. Do you want your objects to move by certain time or do you want to apply the effect immediatly? (what your code looks like) - or do you make this for each rendered frame? in like the updateAtTime function?

Comment: Hi, no I'm not using physics bodies. I'm not looking for animation, just discrete manipulations. Yes, I would do this once for each rendered frame. Thanks. I've actually come up with an answer which I'll post.

Answer (score 1):

I've found an answer. I perform the rotation in local space and translate the node in world space. The nil argument in simdConvertVector converts to world. This accomplishes my goal.

````
```
func applyForce(_ force: SCNVector3, to node: SCNNode) {
        let force = SIMD3<Float>(force)
        let translation = SIMD3<Float>(1, 1, 1) * force
        let newPosition = node.simdConvertVector(translation, to: nil)
        node.simdPosition += newPosition
}

func applyRotation(_ radians: Float, to node: SCNNode) {
    let newTransform = SCNMatrix4Rotate(node.transform, radians, 0, 1, 0)
    node.transform = newTransform
}
```
````